# Jquery background color is not working?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I try to change the background when click the button and change to default color when I try to click another button. I attached my code with this

PHP Dynamic Code for that :

```
<ul id="VerColMenu">
<?php 
      echo '<li class = result>';
    echo '<a href="#" class="direct-link">'.$B->getAttribute('TITLE').'</a>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="menu-id" value="'.$u.'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="slider" value="'.$B->getAttribute('SLIDER').'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="min" value="'.$B->getAttribute('MIN').'"/>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="max" value="'.$B->getAttribute('MAX').'"/>';
        echo '</li>';  ?>   </ul>
```

Click function for button using direct-link class:

```
 $('.direct-link').bind('click',function(){

        var $elem = $(this); 
        var oldBG = $elem.css('background-color');
        $elem.css('backgroundColor', '#FF0000');

    if(!$(this).parents('.sub-menu').length){

      $('.sub-menu').hide(); 

        }               
       //     $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});                   

        var $current=$(this).parent();
        var id=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=menu-id]').val());
        var slider=$current.find('input:hidden[name=slider]').val();
        var min=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=min]').val());
        var max=parseInt($current.find('input:hidden[name=max]').val());            
        button_clk(id, slider, min, max);
    });
```

I need your help to fix this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the actual problem???

Comment: jQuery css() understands both "backgroundColor" and "background-color"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/RuE9N/

Comment: it's working now but i found one more issue in this code. if i clicked the already highlighted menu the remaining menus are changed the background color into red.. How to fix this

Comment: hi do this in my code like this var $elem = $(this); 
            var oldBG = $elem.css('background-color');  
           $('.direct-link').removeClass('on');
            $elem.addClass('on'); is this corect?

Answer (score 0):

In case of jQuery's .css function you can use CSS-like names as well as JavaScript ones. That is you could type:

```
$elem.css('background-color', '#FFFF00');
```

You could also store the default colour in HTML5 data- attribute of the tag instead of JS variable eg:

```
$elem.attr('data-color', $elem.css('background-color'));
```

and when you want to use it again, you can do:

```
$elem.css('background-color', $elem.attr('data-color'));
```

I hope this helps :)